# What is a (preferably) flying carnivorous insect that hunts adult fruit flies at a rate that doesn't threaten extinction?

Tags: experimental-design, experiment, ecosystem, antipredator-adaptation

I am forming an experiment, where I will be forcing evolution on Fruit Flies
(Thanks rogue ant) The experiment goes a bit like this;

I will be forming an ecosystem where every abiotic factor is perfect for the fruit fly, and is supporting its growth and species prosperity. everything down to temperature and humidity, however every biotic factor is trying to kill the fruit flies.

If anybody knows of a species that would work for this, or has miscellaneous tips, or ideas, please let me know.

Comment: You could also test whether the lab strain of flies have lost any predator avoidance behaviours compared with wild-sourced flies.

Comment: Good idea! Will surely look for changed behaviour patterns.

Answer (score 3):

**Biotic fruit fly pathogens / predators.**

You don't need every single one for a basic project.  Here are 2 types.

**Parasitoid wasps**
Parasitoid wasps lay eggs in larva.

> Drosophila in the wild suffers massive mortality from the attacks of
> parasitoid wasps. As many as 80% of Drosophila larvae in natural
> environments may be killed by wasps that lay eggs in them. These eggs
> hatch into larval wasps that devour the fly larva from within. Adult
> wasps then emerge and mate, after which female wasps search for new
> hosts in which to begin the cycle anew.

[source](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-021-22712-0)

**Earwigs, spiders and ants oh my!**
[Predation on Drosophila suzukii within Hedges in the
Agricultural Landscape](https://www.mdpi.com/2075-4450/12/4/305/pdf)

> When we exposed D. suzukii pupae in dry and humid hedges, we found
> that on average 44% of them were predated within four days. The most
> common predators in the hedges were earwigs, spiders, and ants.

There are lots of other mortality causes for fruit flies - fungal infections, bacterial infections, mites, viruses.  But as far as predation these will do.  The parasitoids for the larva and the 3 predators for adults.

Plus those 4 insects will make a sweet icon.

Comment: While I appreciate the contribution, I was mainly looking for something that preys on the adult flies. I will edit the post to mention this, Thank you though!